# I am trying to add SendKeys.WaitSend(""); to my code. but getting an error

Tags: c#

So i am making a script and i need it to run the key presses on programs. but i keep getting an error "SendKeys is not in current context" I am new to c#

```
//MCCScript 1.0
```

MCC.LoadBot(new WatchLamp());

//MCCScript Extensions

/* The ChatBot will access the world on a regular basis to watch for a lamp.
 * This is an example of how the world around the player can be accessed from a C# script. */

```
class WatchLamp : ChatBot
{
    /* == CONFIG == */

    int lampX = 6169;
    int lampY = 250;
    int lampZ = -7492;

    /* == CODE == */

    int checkCount = 0;
    Location lampLoc;

    public WatchLamp()
    {
        if (!Settings.TerrainAndMovements)
        {
            LogToConsole("WARNING: Terrain handling is disabled in INI file.");
            LogToConsole("WARNING: This means this bot cannot watch for lamps.");
            UnloadBot();
        }
        else
        {
            lampLoc = new Location(lampX, lampY, lampZ);
            LogToConsole("Watching lamp at " + lampLoc);
        }
    }

    public override void Update()
    {
        if (checkCount > 10)
        {
            checkCount = 0;
            Material blockType = GetWorld().GetBlock(lampLoc).Type;
            switch (blockType)
            {
                case Material.RedstoneLampOn:
                    //Lamp is on. All right. Nothing to say here.
                    break;
                case Material.RedstoneLampOff:
                    SendKeys.WaitSend("{UP}");
                    SendText("TNT DETECTED AT SOUTH/EAST");
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    LogToConsole("Lamp at " + lampLoc + " is currently turned OFF !!!");
                    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                        Console.Beep();
                    break;
            }
        }
        else checkCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `SendKeys.SendWait("{UP}");` - there is no `WaitSend` method for [`SendKeys`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys(v=vs.110).aspx);

Comment: And the error message would point to a missing `using` for the namespace `SendKeys` is in. However whether `System.Windows.Forms` will work in whatever environment this program runs in is another store.

Comment: So i can't use SendKeys?